# OpenCvSharp HaarClassifier Cascade for Object detection Error

Tags: c#, opencv, visual-studio-2012, c#-3.0

I am using OpenCvSharp 2.4.9 in MS Visual Studio 2012 and its my first experience.
But getting exception (unknown node type) in HaarClassifierCascade continuously. I have tried it in many ways but unable to resolve this issue.

```
OpenCvSharp.CvHaarClassifierCascade cascade = OpenCvSharp.CvHaarClassifierCascade.FromFile("DeerFaceHog.xml");
```

I successfully implement HaarClassifier in C++ but now need it in C#.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since this wrapper is using opencv's deprecated c-api underneath,

you are limited to *Haar* cascades only.

you can neither read HOG, nor LBP cascades using CvHaarClassifierCascade

[edit] : you should use the [CascadeClassifier](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/blob/master/src/OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus/modules/objdetect/CascadeClassifier.cs) instead. do *not* use the outdated c-wrappers in opencvsharp (anything using IplImage), but the c++ ones (using Mat)